# Scala- zip with futures

Tags: scala, future, scala-collections

Below is the code which i am trying to understand:

```
object Tryouts extends App{
    val studentIds= Future{
        List("s1","s2","s3")
    }
    val details = studentIds zip(Future{List("Tim","Joe","Fin")}).map(x=>x.tail)
    details.foreach(println)
    Thread.sleep(1000)

}
```

The Problem:

> val details = studentIds
> zip(Future{List("Tim","Joe","Fin")}).map(x=>x.tail)

Here if you notice, i am not using a "." before zip and just giving a space. I guess that . and space both works in same way and also validated it some stack overflow questions. the above expression before applying a map will result me a Future[(List[String],List[String])]. so when i say

> .map(x=x.tail) should show compilation error in IDE because tail operation can be applied only on list and not for tuple. But it is actually executing successfully.
>
> The same statement when executed with "." before zip function like this:
>
> val details = studentIds.zip(Future{List("Tim","Joe","Fin")}).map(x=>x.tail) the map(x=>x.tail) gives error.

what might be the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you omit the space (by replacing the `.`) you have to also omit the parentheses, otherwise the compiler will consider whatever comes after as part of the initial expression - in your case the `map(x => x.tail)` will be applied to the `Future{List("Tim", "Joe", "Fin")}`.

A simple example can be observed here:

```scala
val y = 3 to(5).toDouble
```

The `#toDouble` is actually applied to the number 5. If you try to use the range defined methods, it won't work.

Going back to your code, if you remove the `.` before the tail call, you will get the expected compile error:

```scala
val details = ids zip Future.successful(List("Tim", "Joe", "Fin")) map (_.tail)
// compile error: "Cannot resolve symbol tail"
```

Comment: What you need to omit (and do in your last line) is not the parentheses around `Future`, it's the dot before `map`. Otherwise, you'd also have to omit them in `map _.tail`.